# Firefox : Open XLSX file not saving file butn opening binary

Tags: php, javascript, excel, firefox

I generate a file server side and I want the client to automatically open it : it's a XLSX file.  Firefox just opens the file and I see the binary content of the XLSX file in the browser, but I want it to be open via a Save As... box.

It works fine in Chrome with the same code (it saves it) but not firefox...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Have a look at this - Php exec and return binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772479/php-exec-and-return-binary)

Are you sending proper headers??
something like

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"yourfile.xlsx\"");
```

**UPDATE**

```
header('Content-Type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.xlsx');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/yourfile.xlsx");
```

**UPDATE 2**

Spread sheet mime types

```
application/vnd.ms-excel [official]
application/msexcel
application/x-msexcel
application/x-ms-excel
application/vnd.ms-excel
application/x-excel
application/x-dos_ms_excel
application/xls
```

**UPDATE 3**

Regarding your javascript problem did you try using

```
location.href instead of window.open ??
```

Comment: The file is generated already... I want the user to be able to open the file which will popup a Save As dialogue.  But when I open the URL of the XLSX file with window.open, it shows the actually binary of the file in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are sending this mime type as the Content-Type header:-

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

So you need to map the .xslx extension to this mime type on the server